# I have json file and for each user i am writing into a file using file.write() but it's writing the last user only using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have json file and for each user i am writing into a file using file.write() but it's writing the last user only using javascript

```
function getUsers()
{
var allsessions = [1,2,3,4,5]
var allsessiontitle = [a,b,c,d,e]

    var usersjson = './users.json'; 
    var usersdata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(usersjson, 'utf8'));

    usersdata.forEach  // User data
    (
        (user)=>
        {
            //console.log(user.FNAME);
            var allsessions = [1,2,3,4,5]
            user = {...user, MYSESSIONS:allsessions}
            //console.log(user)
        \


        }
    )
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `let newArr = array.map(n => n === 1 ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could take the numerical value of the check.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3],
    result = array.map(v => +(v === 1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3];
console.log(array.map(e => e != 1 ? 0 : e))
```